# My website can not searched with Google, but works fine with other search engine

Tags: search-engine-indexing, google-index, title, meta-description

My website has been published for a year and I have set a title and description tags but they don't work.

According to the document guidelines, I found that the website has been included by Google, but the ranking is very low, and there is no description.

Answer (score 1):

**Indexing**

It is indexed by Google, which means that it is searchable with Google.  To see what it looks like, open Google search and type in

> site:music.163.com/st/web-sublicense/home

It will show you how it looks to users.

**Language**

I note that you have not specified the language, you need to do that in this manner

```html
<html lang="en">
```

**Display**
Google decides by itself what it will display, based on correlation between title, description and content (and other rules).

**Ranking**
Ranking is very complex and based on the key words or phrase that your site is about (as long as it is correlated with title and url etc).   And the more external links you have to your site the higher it ranks.

> ..key factors that help determine which results are returned for your query -
>
> - Meaning
> - Relevance
> - Quality
> - Usability
> - Context

From [Ranking Results](https://www.google.com/search/howsearchworks/how-search-works/ranking-results/)

There are websites that check your site.  You can use these to focus on your "key words" and check for errors.  I ran a quick check and its showing 130 errors in css. And the following in html.  You really need to reduce these errors.  I aim for zero errors on my sites.

> Errors (3)
>
> - Element title not allowed as child of element head in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
> - script element between head and body.
> - Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.
> - Consider avoiding viewport values that prevent users from resizing documents.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will modify it according to your suggestion and observe the follow-up effect